# How to measure the Firestore read and write counts on Stackdriver

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stackdriver

I need to monitor real time reads/writes counts of my Firestore database.

I've already created the dashboard with the metrics and the image attached shows the current configuration.

[image: Current graph]

However, this displays a rate (per second). How do I calculate the actual counts? Or is there a different aggregation aligner?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to add ‘count’ into your existing chart, here are the steps:

1. on the Dashboards page, click the 3 dots on the top-right of your chart, select ‘Edit’ from the pop-up menu;
2. On the ‘Edit Chart’ page, under ‘METRIC’ tab, click ‘+ ADD METRIC’, select the ‘Resource type’ you desire and the Metric such as ‘Document Reads’ or ‘Document Writes’, then select ‘count’ in the dropdown list of ‘Aggregator’ and save the change.

Comment: Yes I did these steps, i just need to know the meaning of the rate[X/s], and how to calculate the actual reads/writes counts using this metric

Comment: Based on the selected time period(1h, 6h, 1d, 1w, 1m…...) from the upper-right side on ‘Edit Chart’ page, the rate [X/s] means the average number of operations over the time window. 

Count could be used to aggregate number of operations across multiple time series. By default it will be a single line with values being the result across all the time series.

You could hover the mouse on the metrics of the upper-left of the chart for a brief explanation.